# Python error: "expected an indented block"

Tags: python, syntax-error

I've got the "usual" expected an indented block. All the indentations are right. I've open my script in various editors and there is no issue abt missalignments, or hiden whitespaces caused by tabs.

Would really appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this issue.

### This is the part of the script causing problems:

```
def findCSVs():
'''
looks into a 'tocom_data' subdirectory, finds 'tocomxxx.csv' files,
retuns a sorted list of filenames that conform: begins with TOCOM, ends in .csv
'''
    csvlist = []
    datadir=os.path.join('.','tocom_data')
    flist = os.listdir(datadir)
    for fname in flist:
        fsplit = fname.split('.')
        if len(fsplit)>1:
            if fsplit[1]=="csv" and fname[0:5]=="TOCOM":
                completeFname= os.path.join(datadir,fname)
                csvlist.append(completeFname)
                csvlist.sort()
    return csvlist
```

---

Python expects an indented block at the line `if len(fsplit)>1:`

Much appreciated

Jose

Comment: copy and paste it into a notepad, then check your indentations again

Comment: The doc string should be indented - also, you may want to consider looking at the `glob` module, -`glob.glob('TOCOM*.csv')` for example

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with your docstring at the start of the function. It should be indented as well.

Answer (score 0):

Indent the first line of your doc string.

Just change:

```
def findCSVs():
'''
looks into a 'tocom_data' subdirectory, finds 'tocomxxx.csv' files,
retuns a sorted list of filenames that conform: begins with TOCOM, ends in .csv
'''
```

to:

```
def findCSVs():
    '''
looks into a 'tocom_data' subdirectory, finds 'tocomxxx.csv' files,
retuns a sorted list of filenames that conform: begins with TOCOM, ends in .csv
'''
```

And it should work fine.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of the existing answer. I don't see adding in the (ridiculously verbose) example helps.

Comment: I started writing before the earlier answer was posted, didn't notice, my bad here.